# Can't block cheaters on Mechanical Turk

Tags: amazon-web-services, speech-recognition, mechanicalturk

Recently I've run three studies where MTurk workers listen to a few words of foreign speech and then type in nonsense syllables that sound like what they heard.  The last two times, some workers halfheartedly cheated, not bothering to listen to the speech and typing in words like mooooooo.  This time, some workers skipped listening by using speech recognition software to (poorly) transcribe the speech.  More sophisticated, but still cheating. (This research measures how much better humans are than computers at this.)

When I click on a cheater's name and then click "block this worker," the web page suggests that this will reassign all HITs given to them so far to other workers, and that this worker will no longer be able to submit HITs.  But neither happens.

**How do I stop cheaters from continuing to pollute my data with spurious HITs?**

Comment: Have you submitted a complaint to Amazon yet?  What was their response?

Comment: I would file a complaint rather than trying to stop it yourself. Amazon needs to police their service if they want people to trust using it. Submit a report of the issue, provide usernames and let them boot them.

Comment: OK, I just sent this to help -> contact us -> managing workers.  Let's see what they say.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paraphrase of Amazon's explanation why blocked workers (sometimes) still submit HITs:

When you block a Worker, they may still **submit any HITs they previously accepted** as we can’t remove a HIT from a Worker. However, they can't accept any new HITs.

When you block a Worker, you may reject their submitted assignments, and you may republish those to other Workers.  But this doesn't work for **assignments they have accepted but not submitted.**